# Robot Framework - Get Dictionary Keys - Don't want sorted output

Tags: python, dictionary, robotframework

Is it possible to get the keys of a dictionary (with the "Get Dictionary Keys" keyword or not) without having them sorted in aplhabetic order ?

A little example:

```
# Considering ${Dico}={'a': 1, 'c': 2, 'b': 3}
${keys}=  Get Dictionary Keys  ${Dico}
```

I get:

```
=> ${keys}=['a', 'b', 'c']
```

And I want:

```
=> ${keys}=['a', 'c', 'b']
```

---

PS: In fact, I'm trying to use a loop on a dictionary (and operate on each element in the order they were added!) so if you have a better solution than getting the keys as a list and make a :FOR loop on this list, please feel free to share it! :)

Comment: You cannot control the order in a `dictionary`. Use `OrderedDict` to remember the order of how items are added.

Comment: Thanks, that's what i was searching for :-). Could you please write an answer so I can validate it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done by the use of `OrderedDict`. (Thank you @Rikka for the answer)

For examples on how to use it, see here : [Implement an ordered dictionary in Robot Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35129482/implement-an-ordered-dictionary-in-robot-framework).